# Mocking in java with Junit 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

Currently working on a school project where we are to use TDD with mocking. I'm new to mocking, and I'm having some difficulties with how to mock properly.

I have a Bank class and an Account class where the bank is represented as a hash map filled with Account objects. The Bank class also has a createAccount()-method where a new Account object is created and gets put in the map with a unique account number (key), and returns the account number for the created object.

I want to test how this methods behaves if I get a duplicate key, and I'm fairly sure I need to mock. However I'm stuck with how I should implement this test. The first test is working properly

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BankTest {
    private Bank bank;

    private TransferWriter writer;
    private TransferReader reader;

    @Mock
    private HashMap<Integer, Account> accounts;

    @BeforeEach
    void initialize() {
        bank = new Bank(writer, reader, accounts);

    }

    @Test
    void createAccount_NonDuplicateID_CreatesNewAccount() {
        int accountNumber = bank.createAccount("Test", 2000);

        verify(accounts).put(argThat(acc -> acc == accountNumber),
                argThat(acc -> acc.getAccountHolder().equals("Test")));
    }

    @Test
    void createAccount_DuplicateID_CreatesNewID() {}
}
```

Comment: No, you probaly shouldn't need to mock. And a test is not meant to know how a method behaves. A test is meant to ensure that a method behaves the way it should behave. So you need to know what the method should do before writing the test. We don't, because you haven't said. so it's quite hard to tell you how to write the test.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the clarification. I want the method to create a new ID/number for the created object if the number already exists

Comment: So, create two equal accounts. Add the first one to the bank and check that its account number hasn't changed. Then add the second one and check that its account number has changed. That's the contract of your method, and you don't even need to know that the bank uses a HashMap to test that. And even less to mock that HashMap.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense now, thank you!

Comment: Just for the records: Do **not** mock data structures like `HashMap` (or any other `Collection`), use real objects for that. **---** Mock only classes that provide *behavior* which in your case are `TransferWriter` and `TransferReader`.